# Unhandled exceptions in cpp

Tags: c++

What does "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6832479E5 in ConsoleApplication1MARK.exe.Access violation writing location 0x00005BB287610D9" mean?

Trying to run the program but an exemption was thrown at me and was lead to another window

Comment: Run with Debugger and see from where the exception is thrown. It's not a normal exception, looks like invalid memory access.

Comment: Hi, this error message means that your program tried to write to a memory address that it was not allowed to access. This is a common cause of crashes and bugs in C++ programs, and it is known as a segmentation fault or access violation...  You can use tools such as a debugger, a memory analyzer, or a code analysis tool to help you with this problem

Comment: This is not a C++ exception, but a Windows exception.

Comment: It means your program tried to write to memory that it does not own. There could be several different reasons for why it attempted to do that like accessing an array out of bounds. If you are using Visual Studio you have a debugger. Have it break into the debugger and then switch the "Stack Frame" to your code and inspect the variables to determine what access your program attempted that was not correct.